# How to indicate the temperament to use when playing on a score?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, tuning

If I understand correctly, when you only play in a specific key, just intonation is more exact than equal temperament.
Therefore I would like to how to indicate on a score that a piece should be played with the former. Is there a specific notation for that?

I am especially interested in piano but I guess this is instrument-independent.

Comment: No, I don't know of a way besides simply using text to state your preference, like "This piece is intended to be played only in quarter-comma meantone."

Comment: Oh, and actually there's a lot more to understand than "more exact." Different temperaments are definitely *different*; whether they're preferable is subjective, and carries cultural baggage (including a few centuries of equal temperament). By the way, unless it's *very* important to you, insisting that the piano be re-tuned for the piece might seriously limit how often it's performed!

Comment: @AndyBonner For sure, by "exact" I just meant "closer to the physical definition of harmony" but the choice is ultimately subjective. I use a digital keyboard (can't afford a real one) but I guess this is to take into account for the future. Thanks :)

Comment: This persistent myth is just that, a myth.  Just intonation is not "closer to the physical definition of harmony" if you confine yourself to playing in a single key; it is only true for a subset of chords in a single key.  Even if you spend your entire life playing in C major you're going to want to temper your keyboard.

Comment: ... lest the fifths of your ii and V/V chords sound like this: https://en.xen.wiki/w/40/27